# Unable to get images from downloaded apk expansion files

Tags: android

I have added apk expansion files and succesfully uploaded and dwonloaded , and am unable to access them using

My expansion files are containing images, whuile uploading i have done all in to zip and upoloaded..

below is my code to get images from expansion files...

Can anyone please help me .. how can i get the images

```
ZipResourceFile expansionFile = APKExpansionSupport
                .getAPKExpansionZipFile(context, 1, 0);

// Get an input stream for a known file inside the expansion file
// ZIPs

InputStream is = expansionFile.getInputStream("95065668.jpg");
Log.d(TAG,
      "Assigning obb image to preview image::::::::::::"
            + is.available());
BitmapFactory.Options bfo = new BitmapFactory.Options();
bfo.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is, null, bfo);
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors? What does your LogCat output say? We need more information to work on.

Comment: am getting null pointer exceptioin...the input stream is null

Answer (score 1):

almost you have done, Read your HTML file and convert it to `UTF-8` String. & load as

```
webview.loadData(ur_html_str, "text/html", null);
```

where ur_html is like this:

```
String ur_html_str = "<html><body>youe body contents</body></html>";
```